# Failed to make the following project runnable, access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm getting the following error when I try to build my project

output:

> Project Forum (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2) will be compiled because
>   expected outputs are missing 1>  Compiling Forum for
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2  Compilation succeeded.
>   ...DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : Failed to
>   make the following project runnable: Forum
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2)  reason: Access to the path '...\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\project2\web\src\Forum\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\Forum.exe'
>   is denied.

I've tried different solutions which I have found but none of these have worked:

- Delete project.lock.json.
- Restore solution
- Adding to project.json "scripts": { "postcompile": "postcompile.cmd" } as described here https://conradoclarkdeveloper.com/2016/06/22/net-core-rc-2-tfs-and-you-in-a-pickle-failed-to-make-the-following-project-runnable-access-denied/
- Emptied the bin and obj folders.
- I was advised by many to delete app.config, but I do not have this file.

Comment: Have you tried running Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: make sure that the folder is NOT readonly and rebuild the solution

Comment: Ok. Looks like problem was with antivirus Avast. After i dissabled it, everything works fine.